# Is it possible to browse a website "without a browser"?

Tags: java, web

I was just wondering if it was possible to browse a website (with out the browser UI) and then enter text into a textbox and press a button.

Are there any libraries to do this or any methods in Java to connect to the site and enter information and press buttons.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Search for "headless browser."

Comment: [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

Here's an example of a Google search from their [Getting Started](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted) guide:

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: and if you want it 'headless' go and find the PhantomJS webdriver for Selenium

Comment: @DavidSarmiento What do you mean "headless'?

Comment: No windows showing up. A 'hidden' browser instance.